# Does $f(i)+f(n-i)$ increase as $i$ decreases from $n/2$ to $1$ for any superlinear function f?

Tags: optimization, summation

I have a function f which is superlinear (for example $n\log n$ or $n^k$ for some constant $k$). Is true that for any such function we can prove that $f(i)+f(n-i)$ increases as $i$ decreases from $\frac{n}{2}$ to $1$. That is, the sum is minimized when it is equal to $2f\left(\frac n2\right)$ and increases as the two parts are less balanced.

Would it be easier to prove if we assume that the function and its derivative is monotonous?

Comment: Well, a superlinear function can have any values for $i=1,\dots,n,$ since superlinear is a property of "eventually" being bigger than any linear function. So, this might be true for large enough $n,$ but it definitely isn't true for any $n,i.$

Comment: If the second derivative is positive, then this is true, because the function is convex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: Actually, $f'$ being monotonic and increasing might be enough. Then you can show $f(x-a)+f(x+a)\geq 2f(x)$ by two applications of the mean value theorem. Then let $x=n/2, a=i-n/2$ for $i>n/2.$ You don't need $f$ increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superlinear is a property of being **eventually** larger than any linear function, so we can have literally any values for $n<1000000$ and still be superlinear. So superlinearilty is not enough.

A counterexample would be an $f(x)$ such that $f(n)$ is $n^2$ if $n$ is odd and $n^2/2$ when $n$ is even.

Then you get, when $m$ odd and $n=2m,$  that $f(i)+f(2m-i)$ is minimized at $i=m-1,$ not at $i=m=n/2.$

---

However, if $f'$ is monotonic increasing, we can prove this true.

Let $g(y)=f(x+y)+(x-y).$ Then $g'(y)=f'(x+y)-f'(x-y)\geq 0$ when $y\geq 0.$

So $g$ is monotonic increasing when $y\geq 0.$

Letting $x=n/2, y=i-n/2,$ then $f(i)+f(n-i)$ is increasing for $i\geq n/2.$

Comment: What you have shown is that $f(n/2)$ is minimal. Does your proof also show that $f(x+a)+f(x-a)$ increases as $a$ increases? In particular, I am interested in $f(x)= x \log x$, so if this is an easier case, I'll be happy to know how to handle this case.

Comment: Yes, the simpler way is just to take the derivative with respect to $a$ of $f(x+a)+f(x-a),$ which is $f'(x+a)-f'(x-a)>0$ when $a>0.$

Comment: @Shaharg okay, greatly simplified the answer.